# Setting navigationController.viewControllers messes up the stack later

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, navigationcontroller

I run into a weird issue.
When setting `navigationController.viewControllers` to a new array whose `viewControllers` equal to the current `UIViewController.viewControllers`, then trying to segue to a new `viewController` (push segue), the `UIViewController.viewControllers` is messed up.

To be exact,
I did the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
...
    for(int i=0; i<[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Befor: %d: %@",i, [[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] description]);
    }
    [[self navigationController] setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], self,nil] animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"After: Num of view controllers: %d", [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]);
    for(int i=0; i<[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"After: %d: %@",i, [[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] description]);
    }

}
```

Log results:

> Befor: Num of view controllers: 2 2014-02-15    17:15:01.144[827:60b] Befor: 0:     2014-02-15 17:15:01.145[827:60b] Befor: 1:  2014-02-15 17:15:01.147[827:60b] After: Num of view    controllers: 2 2014-02-15 17:15:01.148[827:60b] After: 0:     2014-02-15 17:15:01.149[827:60b]    After: 1:

Then I pushed a button that segues to another viewController.
Just before the segue this code called:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: Num of view controllers: %d", [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]);
    for(int i=0; i<[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %d: %@",i, [[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] description]);
    }
...

}
```

Log results:

> 2014-02-15 17:15:05.388[827:60b] prepareForSegue: Num of view controllers: 1
>   2014-02-15 17:15:05.389[827:60b] prepareForSegue: 0:

I monitored the `navigationController.viewControllers` at the destination `viewController` and it seems that the `rootViewController` vanished.
When trying to go back (using the navigation controller back button), things got ugly.

I noticed that all this stuff doesn't happen when I assign an array whose objects are different from the current `navigationController.viewControllers`, so it's a workaround for now.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your storyboard. Quite possibly, the pushed view controller is actually modal and wrapped into its own navigation controller.

Compare the addresses of the two navigation controllers that show unexpected numbers of view controllers: perhaps they are different, in which case you should check where you are adding the new navigation controllers.

Comment: I rechecked and all the segues at my storyboard are push style. the The navigation controllers's addresses are the same.